# How do I sort a tab separated file on the nth column using cygwin sort?

Tags: sorting, cygwin

I have a huge tab separated file which I want to sort on its 2nd column. I need to use the tab character as the field delimiter in cygwin sort. So I need something like this:

```
sort -t \t -k 2,2 in.txt > out.txt
```

But the command prompt evaluates '\t' literally and not as the tab character. Note that I need to do this on a Windows machine running Cygwin. Variations such as

```
sort -t "\t"
sort -t \"\t\"
```

don't work, neither does putting this in a cmd file with an actual tab in place of the \t above.

Edit: A solution using either the DOS shell or the Cygwin bash shell is fine.

Comment: Are you using the DOS shell or the cygwin shell (bash by default)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On my machine (Mac bash prompt, GNU sort ...) this works:

```
sort -t '   ' -k 2,2 in.txt > out.txt
```

(A "real" tab between the quotes.)

To get the tab there I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd>).

EDIT: I've now tested it on a Windows machine from the cygwin prompt and it works the same there (as I expected, bash is bash).

Answer (score 13):

You need to add a $ sign in front of the \t to turn on string interpolation, so the tab actually gets sent to sort. This should work in any terminal:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 2,2 in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: This does not work on the Windows command prompt. The error I get is: "sort: multi-character tab `$\\t'"

Comment: I don't include the windows command prompt in "any terminal" =)

Comment: @Nikhil because `''` in cmd isn't a quoting character, and obviously cmd also doesn't has anything like `$''` so it can't work. Use powershell instead although the syntax would be different

Comment: @JoakimLundborg cmd isn't a terminal. It's a shell like powershell, bash, zsh, ksh... and has to be attached to a terminal to work, like conhost.exe (the default terminal for old Windows), Windows Terminal, xterm... Yes it's bad because of compatibility requirements but it's still not a terminal, and in modern Windows powershell should be used instead

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Command Prompt, the simplest solution I found is to disable tab-completion first with:

```
cmd /f:off
```

Then you can type a literal tab character.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a solution for GnuWin32 sort on Windows but none of the above solutions worked for me on the command line. But the following batch file (.bat) worked which is what I wanted anyway. Type the tab character within the double quotes.

```
C:\>cat foo.bat

sort -k3 -t"    " tabfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone see the irony here?
You have to jump through hoops to get the tab character to be a tab...

On Windows command prompt I was able to do it using `c:\bin\sort -t"(actual tab)"` but only after starting the `cmd /f:off` (as hinted above)

On Windows bat file I was able to do the same thing as long as text editor (notepad2 :-) was set to insert tabs as tabs, not spaces.

There are some well-liked hints to use a `-t$'\t"` but I tried about 2<sup>16</sup> combinations of this without luck or remaining hair.