# Sort in Makefile

Tags: sorting, makefile

I have this in my makefile

```
test:
   cat t.txt | sort -t $$'\t' -k 2,2
```

But "make test" gives me this error

cat t.txt | sort -t $'\t' -k 2,2
sort: multi-character tab `$\t'
make: *** [test] Error 2

Works fine on Redhat linux but fails on Ubuntu linux

Comment: quoting is funny in make.  Try using echo to see how the cmd line ends up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$'\t'` syntax you're trying to use is a bash-ism, but by default gmake uses `/bin/sh` as the shell.  You can either override the SHELL variable in your makefile, as in:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

or explicitly invoke bash for this specific command:

```
test:
   bash -c "cat t.txt | sort -t $$'\t' -k 2,2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: What OS is this failing on?

SUGGESTION:

- [How do I sort a tab separated file on the nth column using cygwin sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426647/how-do-i-sort-a-tab-seperated-file-on-the-nth-column-using-cygwin-sort)
- http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Fedora/2008-03/msg02180.html

You can substitute an actual tab, e.g. `sort -t "<Ctl-V><Tab>"`

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Please try the above suggestion (Ctl-V/Tab, or Ctl-V/Ctl-I) and let us know if it works.

Comment: oh it works, hmm, a quick hack though, because $'\t' is a more elegant solution